# Clone git repo from Azure DevOps UI launches Visual Studio 2017 instead of Visual Studio 2019

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops, visual-studio-2019, azure-repos

Summary from [Microsoft Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/891747/clone-git-repo-from-azure-devops-ui-launches-visua.html) since others may face the same issue.

#### Summary

[image]

#### Steps

- Go to the homepage of a repo in Azure DevOps.
- Click the Clone button.
- From the IDE drop down, choose Clone in Visual Studio

#### Expected result

Launches Visual Studio 2019 to clone repo.

#### Actual result:

Launches Visual Studio 2017 to clone repo.

#### Workaround

Start VS 2019, clone from there.

#### Software installed

- Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 16.4.3 (with git for Windows component)
- Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 15.9.19

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Visual Studio version launched is determined in:

- Windows Settings > Default Apps > Choose default apps by protocol.

Details from https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/892419/view.html

[image: answer]

Comment: Thanks for sharing the answer, has this quesiton been resolved, you can accept your psot as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @YangShen-MSFT! This is a reliable workaround, but it is not clear to me how most user can discover this solution. That's why I am sad the community issue is closed.

Comment: For me, 3 different Selectors were available to choose from - all with the exact same icon. I theorised that they might be listed alphabetically so went with the last one in the list to get VS 2019, which worked.